# Google analytics report

Tags: google-analytics, dimension, metric

I am trying to do a custom report which contains the Visit Duration, Visits, Pageviews,where the visit duration is divided into ranges 0-10 seconds, 11-30 seconds, etc. My 3 metrics are Visit duration, Visitors, and Pageviews, however the Visit duration only gives me the length of the visit. How can I get a report with the visit duration divided into ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe what you are asking is possible using a Custom Report, as it doesn't return visit duration ranges.

From what you are describing, it sounds like you'd want the Engagement Report (under Audience > Behavior > Engagement), right?

[image]